# Change default "selected" option in select box after form submission with JavaScript (in Node/ejs file)

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, select, ejs

How can I make the selected option in a select element change dynamically, with the submission (after, really) of an input form which itself depends on the value of the select element?

*details:*

The app is a grocery list with a single input form. A select element with named categories ("fresh", "grocery," "beerandwine", etc) is there. I take the values and use them to route the form, via post, to my node/express app ("/list/fresh/add", "list/grocery/add", etc.). Everything works except for a UI issue I can't crack.

The select element has the "fresh" option selected by default:

```
<option value="/list/fresh/add/" selected>Fresh items</option>
```

I want this default *selected* attribute to change dynamically. So, say someone changes it to "grocery" and inputs "Wheaties," I want the the default option to change to "grocery". Ie:

```
<option value="/list/grocery/add/" selected>Grocery</option>
```

I can't figure out how to make this work dynamically. Nothing happens when I put it in the (one) function I have going on the page, which is what changes the form action depending on the selected option.

```js
  function changeFormAction(){
            myForm.action = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value; 
        }
        
        submit.addEventListener("click", changeFormAction);
```

I have tried making another function and calling that from inside the changeFormAction, but that didn't work, either. I also tried putting an event listener on the form, but I just couldn't get it to do anything.